# Good practice function return static variable

Tags: c

I program on a stm32 microcontroller ( c language ), I made an abtraction layer to load different drivers according to the PCB versions. To abstract from the PCB version as much as possible I did this function which return a pointer to a static variable (but I don't know if this is a good practice?)

NB : (HWI) Hardware Interface

My header file (ledstrip_hwi.h):

```
typedef struct ledStripHwInterface_s{
    bool (*init)(void);
    bool (*isReady)(void);
    void (*reset)(void);
    void (*sleepMode)(void);
    void (*wakeUp)(void);
    void (*setEnable)(bool enabled);
    void (*setLed)(uint16_t index, const uint16_t h, const uint8_t s, const uint8_t v);
    void (*setLedHsv)(uint16_t index, const hsvColor_t *color);
    void (*getLedHsv)(uint16_t index, hsvColor_t *color);
    void (*setStripColor)(const hsvColor_t *color);
    void (*setStripColors)(const hsvColor_t *colors);
    void (*scaleLedValue)(uint16_t index, const uint8_t scalePercent);
    void (*setLedHsvScale)(uint16_t index, const hsvColor_t *color, const uint8_t scalePercent);
    void (*setBrightness)(const uint8_t brightness);
    void (*update)(timeUs_t currentTimeUs);
    uint16_t length;
}ledStripHwInterface_t;

const ledStripHwInterface_t* getLedStripHwInterface(void);
```

Into my source file (ledstrip_hwi.c) :

```
#include "platform.h"
#include "ledstrip_hwi.h"

#if defined(USE_LEDSTRIP_PCA9956)

#include "drivers/pca9956.h"

#elif defined(USE_LEDSTRIP_PCA9957)

#include "drivers/pca9957.h"

#else

#error "Led strip driver not defined !"

#endif

const ledStripHwInterface_t* getLedStripHwInterface(void){
#if defined(USE_LEDSTRIP_PCA9956)
    static ledStripHwInterface_t interface = {
        .init           = &pca9956Init,
        .isReady        = &pca9956IsReady,
        .reset          = &pca9956Reset,
        .sleepMode      = &pca9956EnterSleepMode,
        .wakeUp         = &pca9956WakeUp,
        .setEnable      = &pca9956SetEnable,
        .setLed         = &pca9956SetLed,
        .setLedHsv      = &pca9956SetLedHsv,
        .getLedHsv      = &pca9956GetLedHsv,
        .setStripColor  = &pca9956SetStripColor,
        .setStripColors = &pca9956SetStripColors,
        .scaleLedValue  = &pca9956ScaleLedValue,
        .setLedHsvScale = &pca9956SetLedHsvScale,
        .setBrightness  = &pca9956SetBrightness,
        .update         = &pca9956Update,
        .length         = PCA_LED_STRIP_LENGTH
    };

#elif defined(USE_LEDSTRIP_PCA9957)

    static ledStripHwInterface_t interface = {
        .init           = &pca9957Init,
        .isReady        = &pca9957IsReady,
        .reset          = &pca9957Reset,
        .sleepMode      = &pca9957EnterSleepMode,
        .wakeUp         = &pca9957WakeUp,
        .setEnable      = &pca9957SetEnable,
        .setLed         = &pca9957SetLed,
        .setLedHsv      = &pca9957SetLedHsv,
        .getLedHsv      = &pca9957GetLedHsv,
        .setStripColor  = &pca9957SetStripColor,
        .setStripColors = &pca9957SetStripColors,
        .scaleLedValue  = &pca9957ScaleLedValue,
        .setLedHsvScale = &pca9957SetLedHsvScale,
        .setBrightness  = &pca9957SetBrightness,
        .update         = &pca9957Update,
        .length         = PCA_LED_STRIP_LENGTH
    };

#endif

    return &interface;
}
```

In main.c:

```
#include "ledstrip_hwi.h"

static ledStripHwInterface_t* ledstrip;

static void runAnimationLed(uint8_t duration_secs){

    hsvColor_t red  = {  0,   0, 255};
    hsvColor_t blue = {240,   0, 255};

    while (duration_secs--){

        delay(500);

        ledstrip->setLedHsv(0, &red);
        ledstrip->update(micros());

        delay(500);

        ledstrip->setLedHsv(0, &blue);
        ledstrip->update(micros());
    }
}

int main(void){

    ledstrip = getLedStripHwInterface();

    if ( ledstrip->init() ){
        runAnimationLed(10);
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't they const. They should be const.

Comment: I would do something like that for run-time selection of driver (with `const` slapped on everywhere possible). But this is compile/link time selection of driver. Why not have the drivers in different "*.c" files, exporting the same functions, and compile/link in the right driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To abstract from the PCB version as much as possible I did this function which return a pointer to a static variable (but I don't know if this is a good practice?)

No, it's not good practice. In case of bare-metal MCU programming, then re-entrancy isn't an issue - which would otherwise be a strong argument against code like this. But the main issue is that you are breaking private encapsulation by exposing a read/write variable to the caller. Which contains function pointer members no less. That's a dangerous and brittle interface.

You cast to `const` before returning which improves the situation a lot. This is still read/write RAM but the caller shouldn't modify it unless they do something weird like casting away `const`. The question is why you didn't make these variables `static const` to begin with though? Then they would also end up in flash and not sit in your valuable RAM. It's literally waste of space.